# What does this websocket url "ws://{{$}}/ws" mean?

Tags: url, websocket, go

I work with websocket in go. And I got a websocket url format from a trivial example that I google like this:

```
ws://{{$}}/ws
```

Relatively complete code below:

home.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        ......
        if (window["WebSocket"]) {
            conn = new WebSocket("ws://{{$}}/ws");
            conn.onclose = function(evt) {
                appendLog($("<div><b>Connection closed.</b></div>"))
            }
            conn.onmessage = function(evt) {
                appendLog($("<div/>").text(evt.data))
            }
        } else {
            appendLog($("<div><b>Your browser does not support WebSockets.</b></div>"))
        }
        ......
    });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

And wsServer.go:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)
var addr = flag.String("addr", ":8080", "http service address")
var homeTempl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("home.html"))

func serveHome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ......
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    homeTempl.Execute(w, r.Host)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveHome)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", serveWs)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(:8080, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

I thought it would be a regular expression while actually I can't explain it.

I test it on my own PC browser, and connect success with:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but

```
http://ip:8080 (which ip is my computer's also the litsening server's ip)
```

not. 
And why?

Of course it works when I change "ws://{{$}}/ws" to a certain url. But I want to know why?And what can this expression matching for?

The complete example code is large, I think above is enough to the question. If I miss something you can find out complete example in this page : https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

Comment: Please post your complete example. http://localhost:port working and http://ip:port could mean you are not using the correct ip:port, you are firewalled, you are binding to localhost, etc.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Thanks for your remind. I've already re-edit and have some change on my post. Hope it is clear to you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using the [template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package of Go. The template package supports `{{ placeholders }}` that are annotated by those curly brackets. Those curly brackets might contain statements like `range`, `if` etc, and variable names. The variable name `$` is a special name that points to the root element that was passed to the `template.Execute` method.

Please add the code of your `wsServe` method so that we can see what value your are passing to your template. I will extend my answer afterwards.

Comment: Your answer got the point, and sorry about my carelessness. I add the code you've mentioned, also a link to the complete example. And thanks your answer.